# Can I pass variables to the compare function in sorted method in Python?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
    if(order=="dsc"):
        return sorted(qs, key=compare_function, reverse=True)
    elif (order=="asc"): # asc
        # return sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj.teacher.name)
        return sorted(qs, key=compare_function)
    else:
        pass



def compare_function(obj):

    if obj == None:     
        return "aaaaaaa"
    if obj.teacher == None: 
        return "aaaaaaa"
    else:   
        test = {"teacher": obj.teacher}
        return test.get("teacher").name.lower()
```

What I expect is to pass some additional params to compare_function like below:

```
    if(order=="dsc"):
        return sorted(qs, key=compare_function(cls_name), reverse=True)
    elif (order=="asc"): # asc
        # return sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj.teacher.name)
        return sorted(qs, key=compare_function(cls_name))
    else:
        pass

    def compare_function(obj, cls_name):
        if obj == None:     
            return "aaaaaaa"
        if obj.teacher == None: 
            return "aaaaaaa"
        else:   
            test = {"teacher": obj.teacher}
            return test.get("teacher").name.lower()
```

But as I did this, no param was passed to compare_function. So the "obj" in compare_func will be None.

Then I tried to changed to

```
return sorted(qs, key=compare_function(obj, cls_name), reverse=True)
```

However, the interpretor complained the obj can't be found this time.

How can I do?

Thanks.:)

p.s. I'm seeking for a general solution. :')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multiple arguments to the method 'key' of sorted()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483867/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-the-method-key-of-sorted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a lambda as the key that invokes `compare_function` with an extra argument:

```py
key=lambda x: compare_function(x, cls_name)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks. May I ask you that why? Any reference doc? I have searched for several times but can't find any tips. 
Why didn't the original statment "key=compare_function(obj, cls_name)" work?

Comment: @Alston Because that doesn't pass a function as the key; it attempts to directly call `compare_function` and indeed, `obj` is not defined there.

Comment: Here, `compare_function` is called inside the lambda function, rather than called immediately.

Comment: You could also use `functools.partial(compare_function, cls_name=cls_name)` for this ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)), if it makes more sense to you. But personally I think a lambda is clearer.